# In case of admin login, how to give security credentials in web.xml of Java servlets and how could it be validated from JSP admin login page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

Am Creating a Java Web application where User can register themselves and could login to the application.

But in case of Admin, credentials should already be available and could not be registered from Web page. How the credentials like username and password be provided in web.xml of Servlets? and how the credentials are validated from LoginServlet, once the username and password is submitted by admin in JSP and passed to the LoginServlet?

Comment: can you give more details abaout your setup? where are your users exaclty configured? how many role you have? admins and users? do you have tomcat 7.. do you have already some code? *.jsp *.java etc... how does your web.xml looks like ?

Comment: Just "manually" insert that user in users database in backend?

Answer (score -1):

i think you should first understand container managed security..

For tomcat there is a good example here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24253

and then you could (in case of tomcat) configure your own realm (jdbc, etc...):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

and

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html

this link is also useful in case of Java EE: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncat.html